# module not found in a custom python package

Tags: python-import, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am trying to make a package in Python. I have the following file and directory structure:

```
.
├── ds
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── package_a
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── package_a_b
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── settings.py
├── install.sh
├── LICENSE
├── Manifest.in
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

The code is the following:

**`ds/__init__.py`**

Empty file

**`ds/__main__.py`**

```
from package_a import name_a
from package_a.package_a_b import name_a_b
from settings import config

def main():
    print(name_a)
    print(config)
```

**`ds/package_a/__init__.py`**

```
name_a = 'name_a'
```

**`ds/package_a_b/__init__.py`**

```
name_a_b = 'name_a_b'
```

**`setup.py`**

```
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup

HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

README = (HERE / "README.md").read_text()

setup(
    name="ds",
    version="2.0.0",
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
    ],
    packages=["ds"],
    #packages=find_packages(exclude=("tests",)),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "ds=ds.__main__:main",
        ]
    },
)
```

In order to install I following these steps

```
rm -rf dist
pip uninstall ds
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install dist/ds-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl --force-reinstall
ds
```

the problem is that when I execute ds I got the following message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

if I comment all about settings then I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_a'
```

So python is not finding the packages.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I am curious how you run it in a way, that Python manages to find your Util name, as utils is not a package and or Util is obviously found in utils.files.Util (assuming it is in the __init__.py under files)...

Please add more code, so we could reproduce your environment and provide the exact command line you are running your program with. 

But from what I see, it shouldn't work either ways.

Comment: sorry @wankata to edit late, I added a minimal example

Comment: As it is now, only `ds` is listed in `setup.py`'s `packages`. Which means the sub-packages `ds.package_a` and so on would not be installed. I recommend you use the `find_packages()` technique instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package inside `__main__.py` is available under the name `ds`.

```py
from ds.package_a import name_a
from ds.package_a.package_a_b import name_a_b
from ds.settings import config
```

Comment: if I do that, when I execute the code directly wiht python ds/__main__.py, I have the same problem.

Comment: I would execute code with command `python -m ds`. But the package should be installed first